# How to find control in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any window in Visual Studio 2010 that can be used to find controls?
I want to see the list of all controls used in my project.

Comment: It is on top of the property window.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the property window there is a dropdown menu where all the controls of the open file are listed and you can select them in there. This could be usefull if you have hidden controls not appearing on your form.